# Is it possible to limit the height of a selectmenu widget with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I've been trying to do this by setting the `size` attribute of the source `select` element, but it's being ignored. There doesn't seem to any height setting option for the widget. Is it possible?

The widget is currently working inside a div dialog that has overflow hidden, so the drop-down (26 items, always) just disappears off the div.

Comment: Why can't you add some css rules for that select? Like here - http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render
with custom rendering?

Comment: It would be good if you create a fiddle of your code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no size similar option in jQuery UI Selectmenu (aka show more than just a button but a select "pane"). But it's possible to change the height of the generated button by CSS.

Another idea would be changing the rendering mechanism like @Michael proposed.

A demo fiddle would be useful. When your actual issue is the overflow of the div you could try to add the menu to another element by using the appendTo option, see http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#option-appendTo

Answer (score 4):

How about some css...

```
.ui-selectmenu-open{
        max-height: 350px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: This was the correct and easy solution without any structure changes.

Comment: You get a nicer result with `.ui-selectmenu-open > ul { ... }` because the border is around the <div>, so this makes the list scroll within the border.